# Filling an array of objects with another array returns memory address

Tags: java

```
private Trip[] trips;
private int[] distanceTraveled = new int[] { 8, 6, 15, 5 };

for (int i = 0; i < distanceTraveled.length; i++) {
  trips[i] = new Trip(0, i, distanceTraveled[i]);
}
for (Trip trip: trips) {
  System.out.println(trip.toString());
}
```

I am trying to write the values in distanceTraveled array to fill the array of objects for Trip[], but this code returns. Any help will be appreciated

```
@20ce73ec
@393679df
@56627197
```

Comment: Did you overwrite the `toString` method of `Trip`?

Comment: The toString() method for Object gives you words like that. The default toString() just returns the hashCode() which might be thought of as the memory address of the object. You will need to override Trip#toString() if this is possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Override toString() method in Trip class.

> Refer: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/overriding-tostring-method-in-java/